# Why can malloc allocate more memory than mmap?

Tags: c++, linux, malloc, mmap

I'm experimenting to see how much virtual memory I can allocate on 64-bit Linux, currently running Ubuntu via [repl.it](https://repl.it). I'm using some simple code to find this limit through experimentation by repeatedly calling `realloc()` or `mmap()`. I also use `getrlimit()` with `RLIMIT_AS` to query the OS for the maximum address space.

Here is the output:

```
Soft mem limit: 17592186044415 MB
Hard mem limit: 17592186044415 MB
----------------- Using mmap() -----------------
Trying 32768 MB.. Success.
Trying 65536 MB.. Failed.
----------------- Using realloc() -----------------
Trying 32768 MB.. Success.
Trying 65536 MB.. Success.
Trying 131072 MB.. Failed.
```

This surprised me for a few reasons, which should perhaps each be their own SO question:

1. The title question: **Why can `realloc()` allocate 64GB while `mmap()` fails after 32GB?** Perhaps I'm misusing `mmap()` somehow?
2. Why *can't* `realloc()` or `mmap()` come even close to approaching the memory limit? On a 64-bit process, I would expect hundreds of terabytes of virtual address space available.
3. When removing `PROT_WRITE` and using only `PROT_READ` or `PROT_NONE`, `mmap()` manages to allocate up to 67108864 MB, which is around 64 terabytes (!). How does `PROT_WRITE` cause that allocation to fail? What use would this have (if any) with anonymous mappings?

Here is the code in full, in case that offers any insight:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

const size_t KB = 1024;
const size_t MB = 1024 * 1024;
const size_t GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

void usingMmap(size_t size);
void usingRealloc(size_t size);

int main() {
  rlimit limit;
  getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit);
  std::cout << "Soft mem limit: " << limit.rlim_cur / MB << " MB\n";
  std::cout << "Hard mem limit: " << limit.rlim_max / MB << " MB\n";
  std::cout << "----------------- Using mmap() -----------------\n";
  usingMmap(32 * GB);
  std::cout << "----------------- Using realloc() -----------------\n";
  usingRealloc(32 * GB);
  return 0;
}

void usingRealloc(size_t size) {
  void *p = NULL;
  while (true) {
    std::cout << "Trying " << size / MB << " MB.. ";
    p = realloc(p, size);
    if (p == NULL)
      break;
    std::cout << "Success.\n";
    size *= 2;
  }
  std::cout << "Failed.\n";
  if (errno != ENOMEM)
    perror("realloc");
}

void usingMmap(size_t size) {
  void *p = NULL;
  while (true) {
    std::cout << "Trying " << size / MB << " MB.. ";
    p = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
             -1, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED)
      break;
    std::cout << "Success.\n";
    if (munmap(p, size) == -1) {
      perror("munmap");
      exit(-1);
    }
    size *= 2;
  }
  std::cout << "Failed.\n";
  if (errno != ENOMEM)
    perror("mmap");
}
```

<del>Note that changing the starting size up or down or calling only one of either `mmap()` or `malloc()` did not change this behavior.</del> *Actually,* changing the starting value to 64 GB causes *both* `mmap()` and `realloc()` to fail. I'm starting to think it has more to do with how large an allocation each call can handle at once rather than how much virtual address space a process is allowed to use up.

(I know there's a lot of error reporting code that distracts from the main point; I've kept it there to demonstrate that there aren't any unexpected errors coming from `mmap()`, `munmap()`, or `realloc()`)

Comment: It depends on how memory is laid out and how `malloc()` organizes its heap.

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert but I know some distributions of Linux choose to ignore memory constraints and never fails to allocate (until it exhausts the entire address space), and instead only commits memory on first use of the allocated member, kill the process or killing other processes to free up memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's my understanding, as well. It may be worth noting that repl.it provides only 1024MB of RAM, so we're definitely dealing only with virtual address space and not physical RAM (otherwise `ENOMEM` would occur much sooner).

Comment: Take a look at [overcommit memory](https://www.linuxembedded.fr/2020/01/overcommit-memory-in-linux) for example.